# How Can I Find For Example *.mp3 Files From All Directories Of My System?

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to find the absolute path of all of .mp3 formatted files from every directories of my system.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that questions include a [mcve] including what you've already tried based on your own research and what went wrong with your results

Comment: You've included the Python tag. Are you trying to do this with Python? If so, what's the context? Please read [ask].

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using python, `os.walk` can help you.

Simple code like this can work:

```py
import os

for data in os.walk('d:\\music'): # where to start searching
    dir_path, folders, files = data

    for f in files:
        if f.lower().endswith('.mp3'):
            print(os.path.join(dir_path, f))
```